# How should i send sensible data using JSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

im making a webservice in JSON to get the user data. for example i pass the user id and get the address of that user or i pass the user id and i get his favorites.

for example:

```
<script>
  $.post('http://www.example.com/webservices/get-address.php', {
    userid: "13"
  }, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index) {
      alert(data[index].address);
    });
  }, "json");
</script>
```

but anyone could change the `userid: 13` for `userid:14` and get the address of other user.

(i cant use PHP on Mobile APPs so i cant use `$_SESSION['id']`, i will use localstorage to store the user id)

maybe i should mask the user id with a md5() so they cant guess the "user id" of other users?
which is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a session cookie. They are negotiated when you visit and log in and are trackable. Also, you should use ssl to avoid sniffing of data.

You need to track your session id at the server end somewhere and link it to the user, so if they ask for a user they aren't allowed to see, you return a 4xx code informing them that they aren't allowed to access that resource.

You could use a tripcode as some anonymous boards do, but then you're more limited to providing the facility to see groups of people etc.

Comment: so i just should replace:
 $.post('http://www.example.com/webservices/get-address.php',{
                userid: "13"
             },
for:
 $.post('http://www.example.com/webservices/get-address.php',{
                userid: localstorage.getItem('user-id');
             },

and this would be the correct way of doing it?

Comment: No, userid is fine, but you want a cookie to cross check against.